# modal segue won't engage due to instance selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have twoo buttons underneath the view controller. One of those buttons makes calculations. The second one shows information about these calculations. For the information I' m using a modal segue to another viewcontroller called werkwijzeViewController. The calculations button doesn't pose problems. On pressing the information button I get "UIStoryboardModalSegue popoverController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". What's wrong? I'm uploading some of the relevant code:

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "breuk.h"
#import "verklaringViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tellerVeld1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noemerVeld1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *quotientVeld;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tellerVeld2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noemerVeld2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *berekenKnop;
@property (strong, nonatomic) breuk *breuk1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) breuk *breuk2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) breuk *hoofdbreuk;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *uitkomstNoemerVeld;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *uitkomstTellerVeld;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uitkomstStreep;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverController;



- (IBAction)berekenQuotient:(id)sender;
@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{


    BOOL veldVerplaatst;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tellerVeld1;
@synthesize noemerVeld1;
@synthesize quotientVeld;
@synthesize tellerVeld2;
@synthesize noemerVeld2;
@synthesize berekenKnop;
@synthesize uitkomstNoemerVeld;
@synthesize uitkomstTellerVeld;
@synthesize uitkomstStreep;
@synthesize breuk1;
@synthesize breuk2;
@synthesize hoofdbreuk;
@synthesize popoverController;
```

...

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

```
   UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
   popoverSegue=(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

   UIPopoverController *popoverController;
   popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
   popoverController.delegate = self;

   verklaringViewController *verklaringVC;
   verklaringVC=(verklaringViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;

   ...
}
```

@end

werkwijzeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface werkwijzeViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *af;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *vereenvoudigBreuken;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *vermenigvuldigBreuken;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tabelTellerOntbonden;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tabelNoemerOntbonden;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tabelGgdOntbonden;

@end
```

werkwijzeViewController.m

```
#import "werkwijzeViewController.h"

@interface werkwijzeViewController ()

@end

@implementation werkwijzeViewController
@synthesize tabelGgdOntbonden;
@synthesize tabelNoemerOntbonden;
@synthesize tabelTellerOntbonden;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tabelTellerOntbonden =[NSMutableArray new];
    tabelTellerOntbonden = [((ViewController *)self.presentingViewController).breuk1 ontbindInFactoren:((ViewController *)self.presentingViewController).breuk1.tellerBreuk inTabel:tabelTellerOntbonden];
    NSLog(@"%@",tabelTellerOntbonden);
}


@end
```

breuk.m

```
#import "breuk.h"

@implementation breuk
@synthesize tellerBreuk;
@synthesize noemerBreuk;
@synthesize origineleNoemerBreuk;
@synthesize origineleTellerBreuk;
@synthesize ggd;
@synthesize quotientBreuk;
 ...

   - (NSMutableArray *)ontbindInFactoren:(int)product inTabel:(NSMutableArray *)tabel
    {
        for (int priemfactor=1; priemfactor<=product; priemfactor++)
        {
            while (product%priemfactor==0)
            {
                [tabel addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",priemfactor]];
            }
        }
        return tabel;
    }


    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should post the code for all of your IBAction methods tied to your two buttons.

As a glance, it looks to me like the problem is that your prepareForSegue method blindly casts your segue to type UIStoryboardPopoverSegue, and then tries to access the segue's popoverController property.

Your prepareForSegue method will be called for every segue. You need code in your prepareForSegue that checks the segue identifier to make sure you are dealing wit the correct segue before casting it to a UIStoryboardPopoverSegue.

Comment: I followed your advise. The problem is the following: I first do the popover, then press outside the popover and then I want to engage the modal segue. As you suggested ios thinks the segue is still popover. How can I turn the segue into a modal? The code for modal works if I don't first hit the popover button. But I 'd like to combine them...